# How to get call accounts permission using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I use this [library](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/callkeep) to show a call notification in my app. but this needs a call account permission. I want to know if user give this permission to my app or not like we do in permission handler in flutter but I can't found anything about this call account in that library. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work? Using the `permission_handler` package.

```
                  final _callStatus = await Permission.phone.status;
                  if (_callStatus.isDenied) {
                    Permission.phone.request();
                  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this won't allow phone to ring using callkeep.